# react query with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-query

I'm trying to use react guery to get some sata from this funcktion.

```
export const quotaReservationRefundServiceBankAccount = (
  id: string,
  bankAccountInformation: IBankAccountInformation,
  quotaLegal?: string,
): Promise<Response> => {
  const url = `${appSettings.bffUrl}/api/pregnancies/quotareservations/${id}/bankaccount/refund`;
  const body: IRefundQuotaReservationRequest = {
    language: appSettings.language,
    bankAccountInformation,
    legalDepartmentShortCode: quotaLegal || "",
  };
  return post(url, body);
};
```

I have gotten this fare:

```
  const { data: testData, isLoading, error } = useQuery<string, IBankAccountInformation, string | undefined>(["bankRefundResponse",  quota?.reservation || "Quota.reservation missing", bankAccountInfo, quota.legal], quotaReservationRefundServiceBankAccount, {

      });
```

Typescript gives me this error:

> Argument of type '(id: string, bankAccountInformation:
> IBankAccountInformation, quotaLegal?: string | undefined) =>
> Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'QueryFunction<string, QueryKey>'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

parameters are passed to the queryFn via the queryKey, so you can either destruct the queryKey (first argument to the queryFn) or just use an inline function:

```
useQuery(["key", id, bankAccountInformation, quota], () => quotaReservationRefundServiceBankAccount(id, bankAccountInformation, quota))
```

Comment: It gives me this error:
Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'string | Promise<string>'.
  Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'.
    Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
types.d.ts(7, 89): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

Comment: Likely because `quotaReservationRefundServiceBankAccount` returns Promise<Response>, but you've typed useQuery<string>. Have you tried useQuery without annotating the generics like in my example above?

Comment: Looks like it works. How would I then get the data after the promise. I need to json() the response I guess.

Comment: this should most likely happen in `quotaReservationRefundServiceBankAccount`. `return post(url, body).then(response=> response.json())`;

Comment: What do you do if one af the parameters could be undefined. Can you then stop the query? Now that you can not rap react-query in a condition.

Comment: have a look at the `enabled` option: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries

Comment: I have like this boolean i use with enabled.
`const ternimateWithBankAccountInfoExists:boolean = Boolean(ternimateWithBankAccountInfo?.reservationNnumber && ternimateWithBankAccountInfo?.terminateInformation);`

But my typescript still says ternimateWithBankAccountInfo?.reservationNnumber can be undefined when i use is as a parm for my api call function.

Comment: Yes, the boolean option cannot type narrow. I’ve written about that here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script#type-safety-with-the-enabled-option